# Will monitor display this resolution?

Tags: display, resolution

I've a laptop with a resolution of 1366x768 only. The laptop has a 1GB Nvidia Geforce 230M graphics card.

I also have an LG 23" monitor that can support upto 1920x1080 resolution. If I connect my monitor to my laptop, do you think I can display things on 1920x1080 or will it be limited to 1366x768?

Thanks
Ajay

Comment: fyi: "1920x1080"=="1080p"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends.

**Mirror/Clone mode:** If you mirror your notebook built-in display to the external - the external display will only display as high as your built-in display (1366x768)

**DualView/Extend/Multi-monitor mode:** You can set independent resolutions for each display - 1366x768 on your internal, and then 1920x1080 on the external.

If you disable your built-in display altogether and use your external as primary, you'll be able to use 1920x1080.

Comment: IMHO this is the best answer possible. Agree with it at all the points. The others do not cover one point or another one.

Comment: So, if my graphics card supports 1920x1080, then the monitor will display it in the DualView mode right?

Comment: I wouldn't see why not :) Whether or not your game or application would run acceptably at the larger resolution is a different question though.

Answer (score 1):

With a full gig of video memory available, you almost undoubtedly will be able to achieve 1920x1080 resolution with that laptop and that monitor.

I know that on a considerably lesser video arrangement (I forget the chip, but it's 256M of *shared* video memory), I have no problems driving 1680x1050 on my external monitor -- while also simultaneously driving the built-in 1280x800 display. Now, that's less than your desired resolution, but it's also with 1/4 the video memory.

Now, there's no guarantee you'll be able to play super-finely-detailed games at what amounts to 1080p on that monitor -- but you should be able to use it as a very effective secondary display.

Also, if you were to enable mirroring from your laptop to said display, the secondary display will be limited to your laptop's native 1366x768 (roughly 720P) resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to display at 1920x1080.

According to the [specifications at NVIDIA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_gt_230m_us.html), the card supports up to 2048x1536.

Answer (score 0):

The Geforce 230M is a pretty good mobile card - even a weak card can output at 1080p, this one shouldn't have an issue with it. You should also be able to play HD video quite smoothly with it, and even 3D games! (Maybe not on full, though!)